# Counting number of rows in result of dynamic query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, performance, count

We have a quite elaborate query for which we allow users to use a number of, predefined, filters.
The query involves about 20 tables and as you perhaps can imagine the counting of rows (before paging) in the result is by far the slowest part of the query.

At the moment I'm thinking about making the COUNT query dynamic, by join-ing tables based on the user supplied filters and thus making the COUNT query more lightweight.

E.g.:

No filters given:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(BaseTable.Id) 
FROM BaseTable
```

Filter on some other table:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(BaseTable.Id) 
FROM BaseTable
JOIN OtherTable ON BaseTable.OtherTableId = OtherTable.Id
WHERE OtherTable.SomeColumn = 'criterion'
```

Though conceptually pretty easy to grasp and it's perhaps a few hours work, it could become a bit cumbersome and messy, especially considering the amount of tables involved.

I guess I haven't been the only one having faced this (or a similar) problem, so I was wondering how other people have approached likewise situations. Isn't there some more elegant solution?

Comment: But you have to write the from, join, and where for the regular query anyway?  If you regular query is paging you just need to withhold that part.  Have base, base with count, and base with page.

Comment: One problem with this is that all tables are joined in the 'regular' query, so a DTO can be filled. So there are always two queries involved: one for the data part and one for the count part. The count query doesn't necessarily have all tables joined, while the data query always has.

Comment: So, the extra tables should not break the count.  If they do then the count is wrong.  Even if you separate it out there should be core pieces common to both queries or the count is not correct.

Comment: Indeed, they not break the count, but this is exactly the situation as it stands now. Having many tables joined in the count query impose a severe performance penalty, hence the initial question. Bare in mind we're taling 15+ tables here. The least common denominator would be querying the base table.

Comment: For the third time.  Yes you have a least common denominator.   Put that in a base once.  Then add delta to the base for count query and and delta to that base for page query.   I

Comment: How is this different from what I'm proposing: work from a common base to include tables in the count dependent on the given filters.I fail to see the distinction. Why are you downvoting anyway? This is a valid, practical concern...

Answer (score 0):

Read your question.
You asked for an approach for building count and a select statements.
That is an approach for building those two statements.
I use it and it is neither cumbersome nor messy.
How hard can it be to go through the query builder and put the lines in base, count, or select?
You will need to break up the query into from/join and where/sort.
The select statements will be independent.

```
StringBuilder sbBaseFromJoin = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbBaseWhere = new StringBuilder();

StringBuilder sbCountSelect = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbCountFromJoin = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbCountWhere = new StringBuilder();

StringBuilder sbDTOSelect = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbDTOFromJoin = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbDTOWhereSort = new StringBuilder();
```

go through you current query builder and break out the lines

count = sbCountSelect + sbBaseFromJoin+ sbCountFromJoin + sbBaseWhere + sbCountWhere

DTO = sbDTOSelect + sbBaseFromJoin+ sbDTOFromJoin + sbBaseWhere + sbDTOWhereSort

P.S.  If you have a join that does not participate in the where or select and is severely impacting performance then you need to look at the query.